# To move to next text fieds in table cell

Tags: iphone, uitableview, uitextfield, becomefirstresponder

In my application , there is a table view with 2 text fields per cell. Am assigning tags for each text field. On pressing done button i want to make the next text field the first responder(can be between table cells). But the code now i am using does not work . attaching the present code

```
    NSArray *viewsToBecomeFirstResponder = [tableView subviews];
for (UIView *firstResponder in viewsToBecomeFirstResponder) {
    if ([firstResponder isKindOfClass:[UITextField class]]) {
        if (firstResponder.tag == nextTag ) {
            [firstResponder becomeFirstResponder];

        }

    }

}
```

I am not getting the text fields in the sub view array. I am using custom cell for table cells. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With little modification to Karim's code you can access the textVies like this:

```
- (void)textViewDidEndEditing:(UITextView *)textView {
   //Get the indexPath for the currently selected cell
   NSIndexPath *cellPath = [(UITableView*)[self view] indexPathForSelectedRow];

   //Get the actual cell
   CustomTableCell *cell = (CustomTableCell *)[(UITableView*)[self view] cellForRowAtIndexPath:cellPath];

   int currentTag = textView.tag;
   int nextTag = currentTag + 1; // or something else

   UITextView *nextTV = [cell viewWithTag: nextTag];
   [nextTV becomesFirstResponder];
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: @xydev, can you be more specific? What is not working? There could be lot of things wrong, not necessarily the code above.

Answer (score 1):

Define a method as listed below –

```
- (UITextField *) nextToRespondAfterTextField:(UITextField*)textField {
    NSInteger nextTag = textField.tag + 1;

    CustomTableCell *theCell = (CustomTableCell*)[textField.superview];
    for ( UIView *aView in theCell.subviews ) {
        if ( [aView isKindOfClass:[UITextField class]]) {
            if ( aView.tag == nextTag ) {
                return aView;
            }
        }
    }

    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForCell:theCell];

    NSInteger section          = indexPath.section;
    NSInteger row              = indexPath.row;
    NSInteger numberOfSections = [self.tableView numberOfSections];

    if ( [self.tableView numberOfRowsInSection:section] != (row + 1) ) {
        indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:(row + 1) inSection:section];
    } else {
        do {
            section++;
        } while ( section < numberOfSections && [self.tableView numberOfRowsInSection:section] == 0 ) ;

        if ( section == numberOfSections ) {
            return nil;
        } else {
            indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:section];
        }
    }

    theCell = (CustomTableCell*)[self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    if ( theCell == nil ) {
        return nil;
    }

    for ( UIView *aView in theCell.subviews ) {
        if ( [aView isKindOfClass:[UITextField class]]) {
            if ( aView.tag == nextTag ) {
                return aView;
            }
        }
    }   

    return nil;
}
```

Elsewhere,

```
UITextField *nextField = [self nextToRespondAfterTextField:textField];
[nextField becomeFirstResponder];
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using tag to identify your textview. Another way can be to use text view delegates.

```
- (void)textViewDidEndEditing:(UITextView *)textView {
int currentTag = textView.tag;
int nextTag = currentTag + 1; // or something else
UITextView *nextTV = [self.tableView viewWithTag: nextTag];
[nextTV becomesFirstResponder];
}
```

Comment: no use.. text fields are inside table cell not table view.. we will not get indirect subviews..