# Next button don't navigate through UITextField

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, delegates, uitextfield

After a some time, searching here for some solutions we found this post:

[How to navigate through textfields (Next / Done Buttons)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1347779/how-to-navigate-through-textfields-next-done-buttons)

We tried that but unfortunately it doesn't work at all. Note that we put the `UITextFields` inside a `UITableView`.

We think the problem is around the Delegates but we don't know how to deal with it. Following i show you our code:

**.h:**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface LoginViewController : UIViewController <UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, UITextFieldDelegate> {

    UITableView *loginTableView;
    UITextField *textField;

}

@property UITableView *loginTableView;
@property UITextField *textField;
@property UIButton *loginButton;
@property UIButton *cancelButton;

@end
```

**.m:**

```
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>
#import "LoginViewController.h"
#import "RootViewController.h"

@interface LoginViewController ()

@end

@implementation LoginViewController

@synthesize loginTableView, textField, loginButton, cancelButton;

- (void)viewDidLoad {

    [super viewDidLoad];

    // Make rounded corners view
    [self.view.layer setCornerRadius:4.0];
    [self.view.layer setMasksToBounds:YES];
    self.view.layer.opaque = NO;
    self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

    // Create background image view
    UIImageView *loginBackgroundImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.bounds.size.width, self.view.bounds.size.height+20)];
    // Create background's image
    UIImage *backgroundImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"loginbackground.png"];
    loginBackgroundImageView.image = backgroundImage;
    [self.view addSubview:loginBackgroundImageView];

    // Create logo's image
    UIImage *logoImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"logo.png"];

    // Create logo's image view
    UIImageView *logoImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(self.view.bounds.size.width/2 - logoImage.size.width/2, self.view.bounds.size.height/9, logoImage.size.width, logoImage.size.height)];

    // Set image to logo's image view
    logoImageView.image = logoImage;

    [self.view addSubview:logoImageView];

    // Create login table view
    loginTableView = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(self.view.bounds.size.width/2 - (self.view.bounds.size.width/1.2)/2, self.view.bounds.size.height/3, self.view.bounds.size.width/1.25, 100) style:UITableViewStylePlain
                      ];
    loginTableView.delegate = self;
    loginTableView.dataSource = self;

    // Create login container table view
    UIImage *containerImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"loginform.png"];
    UIImageView *containerImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(self.view.bounds.size.width/2 - containerImage.size.width/2, self.view.bounds.size.height/3, containerImage.size.width, containerImage.size.height)];
    containerImageView.image = containerImage;
    [self.view addSubview:containerImageView];

    // Custom table view
    loginTableView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    loginTableView.separatorColor = [UIColor clearColor];

    // Disable scroll
    loginTableView.scrollEnabled = NO;

    // Add login table view to main view
    [self.view addSubview:loginTableView];

    // Create buttons images
    UIImage *loginImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"loginbtn2.png"];
    UIImage *cancelImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"cancelbtn.png"];

    // Create buttons
    loginButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    cancelButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];

    // Set buttons' normal state image
    [loginButton setImage:loginImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [cancelButton setImage:cancelImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    // Place buttons
    loginButton.frame= CGRectMake((self.view.bounds.size.width/2)-(loginImage.size.width/2), self.view.bounds.size.height/1.65, loginImage.size.width, loginImage.size.height);
    cancelButton.frame= CGRectMake((self.view.bounds.size.width/2)-(cancelImage.size.width/2), self.view.bounds.size.height/1.375, cancelImage.size.width, cancelImage.size.height);

    // Set buttons' action
    [loginButton addTarget:self action:@selector(loginButtonPressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [cancelButton addTarget:self action:@selector(cancelButtonPressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    // Set button to the main view
    [self.view addSubview:loginButton];
    [self.view addSubview:cancelButton];

}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {

    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];

}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{

    return 2;

}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell"];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"Cell"];
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
        cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
        if ([indexPath section] == 0) {
            textField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(50, 11, 200, 25)];
            textField.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = NO;
            textField.textColor = [UIColor darkGrayColor];
            textField.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
            if ([indexPath row] == 0) {
                textField.placeholder = @"Username";
                textField.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeEmailAddress;
                textField.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyNext;
                textField.autocorrectionType = UITextAutocorrectionTypeNo;
                textField.autocapitalizationType = UITextAutocapitalizationTypeNone;
                textField.tag = 0;
            }
            else {
                textField.placeholder = @"Password";
                textField.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeEmailAddress;
                textField.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyDone;
                textField.autocorrectionType = UITextAutocorrectionTypeNo;
                textField.autocapitalizationType = UITextAutocapitalizationTypeNone;
                textField.secureTextEntry = YES;
                textField.tag = 1;
            }
            textField.clearButtonMode = UITextFieldViewModeAlways;
            textField.delegate = self;
            [textField setEnabled: YES];
            [cell addSubview:textField];
        }
    }
    if ([indexPath section] == 0) { // Email & Password Section
        if ([indexPath row] == 0) { // Email
            cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"usernameico.png"];
        }
        else {
            cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"passwordico.png"];
        }
    }
    else { // Login button section
        cell.textLabel.text = @"Log in";
    }
    return cell;    
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *) tableView {
    return 1;
}

-(BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField*) formTextField {
    NSInteger nextTag = formTextField.tag + 1;
    // Try to find next responder
    UIResponder* nextResponder = [textField.superview viewWithTag:nextTag];
    if (nextResponder) {
        // Found next responder, so set it.
        [nextResponder becomeFirstResponder];
    } else {
        // Not found, so remove keyboard.
        [formTextField resignFirstResponder];
    }
    return NO; // We do not want UITextField to insert line-breaks.
}

- (void)loginButtonPressed: (UIButton *) sender {

}

- (void)cancelButtonPressed: (UIButton *) sender {

}

@end
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the table.  When you ask you text view for it's superview, it will return the cell, which doesn't contain any other siblings.  Try:

```
UIResponder* nextResponder = [tableView viewWithTag:nextTag];
```

Comment: Hey danh! I totally make sense what you said about tableView so I just tried what you said but it doesn't work either. I've seen I'm having a lot of trouble with textField and tableView delegates. Now, some times, by just clicking the textField, the app crashes unexpectedly so I'll try to do it without the tableView, just with textFields, at first and get it working. Then I'll add the tableView if necessary. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Give tag to your textField one by one and use textField delegate

```
-(BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField
{
    int NextTextField = textField.tag+1;

    UITextField *txt = (UITextField *) [tableView viewWithTag:NextTextField];
    [txt becomeFirstResponder];
    return NO;
}
```

Comment: It doesn't work. I don't know why but when I enable the textField delegate, the app crashes selecting one of the textfields.

Comment: how many textField do you have and ..whats the tag value for all

Comment: Sorry! I was too busy with university so I'm back this weekend to make it working. I currently have two textfields as .m shows it.

Comment: changing: self.view to tableView

Comment: its self understanding dude... and i am also using tableView and getting my textField using this...

Answer (score 1):

Creare an array with your UITextField inside the `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method..

```
[txtArray addObject:textField];
```

and then this bellow method it will work...

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField {
    int i=[txtArray count];
    int x=textField.tag+1;
    UITextField *nextTextField = (UITextField *)[txtArray objectAtIndex:x];
    if (x<i-1) {
        [nextTextField becomeFirstResponder];
    } else {
        [textField resignFirstResponder];
    }
    return YES;
}
```

i hope this help you...

Comment: @RogerFernandezGuri also look in to this answer also ... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6081325/to-move-to-next-text-fieds-in-table-cell